# android onCreate confusion

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, oncreate

Every example I find for any code makes use of onCreate(). For many of the classes I am writing for a program, I had to pass in the initial Activity as the classes required access to what is currently on display (EditText, Button, etc). I had attempted to make each class extend Activity but this typically resulted in run-time exceptions and failures. Currently, each class that requires input from the related View must make use of "parentactivity".findViewByID(...).getData().

Is this the proper way to request data from a View? Should I create respective View objects (EditText, Button, etc) and attach those to the loaded views, then request data from there?

On what I perceive to be a related issue, I had attempted to create a RelativeRadioGroup of ToggleButtons (ToggleButtons in a RelativeLayout in a RadioGroup), only to find that the android:onClick attribute for them is not calling the available method. I have the method in the primary startup class (as well as a few other classes so as to pass the data to where it is needed). While I determined it is unlikely to call the method where the data is required (where the method was originally ONLY located), I do not understand why it is not called in the main class.

Comment: Do you want to pass data between activities? Post some code to clarify your question please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to the radiobutton, did you add the listener?

As for passing data from views I've taken two approaches. If I have used a stock View in the Activity I get the data and then pass only the data to where I need it. Or if its a Custom View I've added my own getData() like method to conveniently get the data in the format I need it.

Don't pass your Activity around just so you can access its View's data.

Comment: Would it be better to make every class an Activity (provided it requires access to the View)? Then use that to implement the Listener?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking that in relation too?